# Extended Entity-Relationship Model to tables (subclasses)

Tags: database, entity-relationship, eer-model

In the EER model there are subclasses entities. I was wondering what's the way to implement that in a real SQL Table or if there is any guide that might help me out to understand how to implement entities subclasses into tables that would help. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Martin Fowler's book [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://www.martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html) covers solutions for subclassing tables:

- [Single Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html)
- [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html)
- [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html)

These correspond to the options in the answer from @spencer7593, without being tied to Java & Hibernate.

Comment: +1. This is a better answer than my answer. (No one likes to be tied to Hibernate, but the documentation is invaluable if you are tied to it.)

Answer (score 3):

The Hibernate documentation has discussion of the options available for representing inheritance hierarchies in a relational database. There are undoubtedly better tutorials, but the Hibernate ORM (love-it-or-hate-it) wrestled with this problem.

Because there is no single "best way" to represent an inheritance hierarchy, they support all the options:

- table per class hierarchy - basically one table, with all the attributes from all the subclasses. lots of columns will likely be null on lots of rows
- table per subclass - one table for the superclass, and a separate table for each subclass
- table per concrete subclass - separate table for each subclass (no table for superclass)

There's no single right answer. Each of these approaches benefits and drawbacks.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/inheritance.html

Comment: +1 Yep, Hibernate is a concrete implementation of these patterns, and if the OP is using Java, it's very relevant.